# Create iOS Home Screen Shortcuts on Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari

I have a web app that allows the user to add the web page to his home screen on the iphone.

That functionality exists with Safari.

Now they released the chrome browser for the iphone too. My question is how can I instruct the user to add the web page to his ios home screen. The chrome browser doesnt seem to have that functionality..?
Can I add a shortcut from chrome options so that it would appear on the iphone home page?

Comment: Does anybody know if this feature will be coming because I think Google is actively promoting PWA, and without this feature Chrome on iOS would be a big issue.

Answer (score 25):

For completeness:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

> Does Add to homescreen work on Chrome for iOS?
>
> No.

Answer (score 20):

Can't change the default browser, but try this (found online a while ago). Add a bookmark in Safari called "Open in Chrome" with the following.

```
javascript:location.href=%22googlechrome%22+location.href.substring(4);
```

Will open the current page in Chrome. Not as convenient, but maybe someone will find it useful.

[Source](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/263661-iphone-chrome-shortcuts)

Works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in a URL to open in Chrome using this Javascript?

Comment: @JoshuaDance at the end, you can replace the location.href with a url

Answer (score 10):

The is no API for adding a shortcut to the home screen in iOS, so no third-party browser is capable of providing that functionality.

Comment: How did you do the functionality for the user to add to the home screen? Or was it just an instruction to use the browser buttons?